# Recursively rename files

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

there is a whole bunch of files all of them who have the pattern

```
joob_1_1
joob_1_2
joob_2_1
joob_2_5
```

so it is joob then underscore numeric underscore numeric - these are also the only files in the folder if that makes it easier. I want to rename them into

```
job_1_1
job_1_2
job_2_1 ....
```

there has to be some way to do that automated ? It is just getting rid of that single letter

Comment: Recursively seem to imply these files are in different folders in a directory tree. Is this correct? Please edit the question with new information.

Answer (score 4):

Use `rename` :

```
rename 's/^joob/job/' joob_*
```

This will change the file names starting with `joob` to `job`.

**Test :**

```
$ ls
joob_1_1  joob_1_2  joob_2_1  joob_2_5

$ rename 's/^joob/job/' joob_*

$ ls
job_1_1  job_1_2  job_2_1  job_2_5
```

Comment: Good examples: http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-bulk-rename-files-in-linux-in-the-terminal

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the gui way, here is an alternative to the very good suggestion of heemayl. You can try krename:

```
sudo apt-get install krename
```

this is as powerful as rename (with the exception that it can't be piped to in a script).
[image]